# Scheduling a visual studio load test using powershell giving me BSOD

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, schedule

I have a visual studio load test which I want to run every hour so that I can start to collect some data.

To do this, I thought it would be best to make a little powershell script and put a command like this inside:

> Invoke-Expression -command "& '$env:VS100COMNTOOLS..\IDE\mstest.exe'
>   /testcontainer:`"C:\Users\benb\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\BBPerformanceTest\bin\Debug\HomePageOnly.loadtest`""

That command works fine, but sometimes when its run I get a blue screen of death.  However, when I run my load test through the visual studio GUI, I never get a BSOD.

two questions:

1. is it possible to avoid this BSOD?
2. Is there another way I can schedule my load test?

Thanks

Comment: How about [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)? You can create a task that executes `MSTest.exe` with your arguments.

Comment: Thanks Schaliasos.  This seemed to fix it.  I just made the scheduled task call MStest.exe directly, rather than through a powershell script... no more BSODs.

Comment: You 're welcome. Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just called MStest.exe directly in the scheduled task (rather than indirectly through a powershell script).  This seemed to solve the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to analyze the memory dump file to find the root cause of your crash (it might not be the load test). This article contains information on how to do that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263

In response to your second question: you can also use a batch file instead of a powershell script.

I hope this helps.